# Easiest way to get character into ASCII-number into binary format in Python

Tags: python, ascii

I know this question was answered in a huge variety of questions already. Although I read a lot here on stackoverflow I cant find the best way to achieve the following:

I parse through a string and get a list of different substrings. Then I want to parse through each string and replace the characters with their binary representation.

However I dont know how to not lose the leading zeroes. I could use this  but I really dont know how to get rid of the binary indicator in front. The goal is to just get a huge array of ones and zeroes

```
>>> format(14, '#010b')
'0b00001110'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `bin(int)` and remplace int with the number and you are going to get the bit representation of the number. If you want to remove the `"0b"` before the bits you can do `bin(int)[2:]` using container slicing.